# IDA not allowing Memory Mapping

Tags: ida

I own an electronic instrument that has video display which has a horizontal timing issue.  The graphics display initialization is done in a 256K bootrom and the desire is to use IDA to reverse the bootrom and patch the timing issue.  The instrument is designed with Motorola 68030 processor and I've taken the time to map out the IO addresses for the graphics IC.  Just to mention that I am weak with the 68K architecture.

I've used IDA for several projects but never to reverse firmware.  With the 68000 processors all of the IO is memory mapped but nowhere in the analysis setup can I determine how to set the memory mapping information.  From the Options-General-Analysis window the Memory mapping is greyed out.

[image]

Is it not possible to apply the memory mapped IO addresses?  What am I missing here?
Thanks for your input.
Jim

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new segment for the addresses belonging to the MMIO ranges. See Edit > Segments > Create segment.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I knew you could setup different segments but I was confused as to *why* there would be a 'memory map' option.  Any idea how to use that feature.